# Running .exe in cygwin opens windows console with MapViewOfFileEx error, how do I fix this?

Tags: c, path, cygwin, fatal-error

I'm trying to run programs I've compiled with GCC. When I run them through cygwin, a windows terminal opens for a couple of miliseconds (or so) giving off the error:

```
 fatal error - MapViewOfFileEx shared 5'(0x66). win32 error 6. Terminating
```

It's followed by a stack trace. (this was the best shot, had to use video camera)

[image: The error terminal]

It doesn't seem to affect the programs but since it's a "fatal error" I suppose it would be good to fix. I tried googling the error, and found that multiple cygwin1.dll in the path shown when running the command

```
cygcheck -s
```

could be the cause, but I only found 1 cygwin1.dll.

The problem could have come from when I tried to open a cygwin-created executeable in windows and I read that I should copy the cygwin1.dll into my windows-folder but I simply deleted it after realizing that I needed several more files (libraries).

Comment: What does the program you've compiled do? Does it call MapOfViewFileEx?

Comment: Also, error 6 means ["The handle is invalid"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx).

Comment: I only include 'ncurses', 'pthreads' and 'string' and only use basic functions from these. This happens with every gcc-compiled executeable I have so I doubt it has to do with the code.

Comment: I don't call `MapViewOfFileEx` explicitly at least. Never heard of it before. They talk of memory address for the "view" [Microsoft - MapViewOfFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: you do realize that executables created under cygwin are only expected to run under cygwin, not under windows?

Comment: Yeah I kind of realize that by now. I am although trying to run under cygwin but to me it seems another instance of the program is still trying to run under windows or something.